# Which technology is most suitable to develop Add-In for MS Excel

Tags: c#, excel, add-in, excel-addins

I need to develop an Add-In for Microsoft Excel and that will run on all operating systems and I need a strong collection set like (Datatable, Sorted list in C#).

Initially, I have developed one VSTO Add-In by using C#, but it is not running on MAC OS because MAC does not have COM technology.

Comment: We need more questions like this one to help highlight what is possible and what is not with the tools currently available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only Addin technology that works across a wide variety of end-points and operating systems is Office Addins, using Javascript, CSS and HTML.

See my blog post here for an overview of all the current Excel addin technologies.
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2017/03/13/excel-javascript-api-part-1-overview-comparison/

Comment: Great Post @Charles Williams but I am puzzled to create a ribbon and form-based application with Office Addins, using Javascript, CSS and HTML. could you provide me some referances?

Comment: Great post! I am pretty much impressed your analysis with time stamps.

You said Excel COM and Automation API (VBA only) will run Windows and Mac Desktops.
Could you give me a simple example?